# How to determine if 'SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges' was passed to Interop.Word.Document.Close()

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, interop, vsto

I have an issue with an Office addin I'm working on, which is implemented for Office 2003 & 2007. The addin is written in VB.NET 3.5 using VSTO.

The problem comes from some external code which automates a mail merge, opening the mail merge template, merging and then closing the template document. The close is done with this code:

```
objWord.Documents(sDoco).Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges, OriginalFormat:=wdPromptUser
```

Because of some logic in my addin, instigated from the `Interop.Word.Application.DocumentBeforeClose` event, a message box is opened which prevents the Office document from closing, which breaks the automation.

Is there a way for me to determine the `SaveChanges` parameter (if any) on a Close within an `Office.Interop.Word.Application` event, such as `DocumentBeforeClose`? I'm trying to capture this parameter and determine if it's set to `wdDoNotSaveChanges` so that I can work around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you get the DocumentSave event BEFORE the DocumentBeforeClose, so set a flag in it, and if that flag is set at close, you know the doc has been saved, but if not, it was not. I've had to do similar things to know whether a Document was SAVED-AS vs just SAVED.

I'm not aware of any way to interrogate the state of that parameter from DocumentBeforeClose.

Comment: This doesn't really help with what I need to do, I'm not trying to determine if the document has been modified (it is always modified in this situation) but whether external code is forcing the document to close without prompting to save. If that is the case I need to mimic that behaviour and let the document close without prompting to save, whereas in other normal use I want to let it continue and do the usual Save prompt.

Comment: Actually, I think this is a solution, you just didn't explain it very clearly :P

Comment: That could be. At work, my answers often get a little terse. Sorry about that.